# How to get the result of an async fetch request into my layout in gatsby js and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, gatsby, fetch-api

I have the following fetchData async function returning a message froma lambda function I want to take that response and dump it onto my page I am using the react-hooks-async package, with a useEffect inside of it. However when I start the function isnide the useAsyncTask it just contiunally runs and never gets the result. I could do it if I hooked up a button to the start() function and it would display correct, but I want it to run on load.

I am using Gatsby JS and react

```
var fetchData = async function run() {
      const response = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          customer_id: parsed.session_id,
        }),
      })
        .then(res => {
          return res.json()
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      console.log(response)

      return response
    }

    const Customer = () => {
      const { start, started, result } = useAsyncTask(fetchData)

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("result")
        console.log(result)
        console.log("result ends")
        start()
      }, [result])

      return (
        <div>
          {started && "Fetching..."}
          <div>Name: {result && result.message.customer_id}</div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was over engineering it. All that was required was the following

```
fetchData().then(value => console.log(value))

    const Test = () => {
      const [data, setData] = useState("")

      useEffect(() => {
        fetchData().then(test => {
          setData(test)
        })
      }, [])

      return data && <p>{data.message.customer_id}</p>
    }
```